# How to write a simple logger which writes time, error and stdout to a file

Tags: bash

I want to create a simple command which logs the date/time, error and stdout to a file. So if I move a file to a folder and it says "Permission denied", I get a line in my file which shows the current date/time and also the error.

I know how to write the stdout and the error of a command to a file but how do I add a time? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that can help:

```
function add_date() {
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        echo "$(date): $line"
    done
}


{
# Your code here
} 2>&1 | add_date   >>   $LOGFILE
```

This will add the date to the beginning of every line output by your code ( between the braces anyway).

There may be some issues with output buffering.  This will appear as the same timestamp on all the lines in your logfile.

Here's an example of the code above applied:

```
: ${LOGFILE:=logfile}
function add_date() {
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        echo "$(date): $line"
    done
}


{
  for a in {1..10}
  do  
    echo $a
    sleep 2
  done

} 2>&1 | add_date   >>   $LOGFILE
```

And the results:

```
$ cat logfile
Thu Mar 28 14:50:46 EDT 2019: 1
Thu Mar 28 14:50:48 EDT 2019: 2
Thu Mar 28 14:50:50 EDT 2019: 3
Thu Mar 28 14:50:52 EDT 2019: 4
Thu Mar 28 14:50:54 EDT 2019: 5
Thu Mar 28 14:50:56 EDT 2019: 6
Thu Mar 28 14:50:58 EDT 2019: 7
Thu Mar 28 14:51:00 EDT 2019: 8
Thu Mar 28 14:51:02 EDT 2019: 9
Thu Mar 28 14:51:04 EDT 2019: 10
```

Comment: The `moreutils` package includes [`ts(1)`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/ts.1.html) for this very purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect stderr to stdout like so:

```
2>&1
```

then add the time before each line of either like so:

```
sed "s/\(.\)/`date` \1/"
```

so we wind up with something like this

```
2>&1 | sed "s/\(.\)/`date` \1/"
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a function to do something like what you're asking for

```
status_msg () {
   echo "`hostname --short`:`date '+%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S'`: $*"
}
```

The above function can be called via

```
status_msg "This is a test line"
```

Which would result in

```
hostname:03_28_2019_13_50_31: This is a test line
```

Or if you're running a command which produces output, you can use it like so ..

```
<command> 2>&1 | while read -r line
do
   status_msg $line
done
```